# pip install behaviour on ">=" dependency tree

Tags: python, pip, versioning

In my team, we have a complex dependencies tree. Some "base-packages" are required in different versions in "top-level" packages. For example, let's say we have:

- The base-package `x`, latest version `1.5.1`.
- The repo `my-service`, that requires (inside `requirements.txt`):

  - Package `x>=1.3.5`.
  - Package `a`, that reuires `x>=1.3.2`,
  - Package `b`, that reuires `x>=1.3.7`,
  - Package `c`, that reuires `x>=1.4.0`.

Questions:

1. When we run `pip install -r requirements.txt`, what version of `x` will be installed? (the reason im not validating this myslef is that our situation is currenlty more complex and not as descibed here).
2. It is easy to see that the **minimal required version** for `my-service` is `x==1.4.0`. Can we pass some sort of flag to pip in order to tell it to install `x==1.4.0` and not `x==1.5.1` (latest?)

Thanks.

Comment: According to the docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#satisfying-requirements), pip will use `the simple rule that the latest version that satisfies the given constraints will be installed`, no mentioning of any flag that would say otherwise. Why would you not want the latest version that satisfies all requirements?

Comment: In case `x` is a third-party, on a deployment, we don't want pip to install a new version that we haven't tested yet.

Comment: Would doing something like `x>=1.3.5,<1.5.0` do the trick for you, i.e. putting the latest version you have tested as an upper limit?

Comment: It would, just wanted to avoid maintaining two-way condictions

Comment: You made the two-condition. So, you have to implement it.

Comment: @KlausD. Not sure I agree. I don't want to bound versions from above and mantain that limit, I just want to install the minimal required version given a set of conditions.

Comment: Two conditions. You can try to re-formulate them in one sentence, but they remain two.

Comment: It has the exact same amount of information as the original definition. It states "the **latest** version that satisfies the given constraints", I suggest "the **minimal** version that satisfies the given constraints".